# Why is the FuelPHP REST API not working without WWW in the domain name?

Tags: api, rest, fuelphp

I'm using FuelPHP to develop a website and have used the REST-API.

My website is using a similar domain name like `http://www.mydomainname.in` but if I browse using 'http://mydomainname.in' i.e. without typing 'www' the api is returning blank , I am calling this api using a Jquery ajax call and **with domain `http://www.mydomainname.in` it is working fine**.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is your website working using Fuel on the domain without www?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply ,Yes , My pages are working and i am trying to get some api json data but it is returning blank . one more thing i am accessing page by without www but accessing api with www . should i change the api call on the basis of page url ????

Comment: Since you're using an AJAX request, I think the problem is related to browser's access control policy, because your request is considered a cross domain request.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve the REST controllers with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

To make **non-www** controllers be accessible by **www** pages, use the header like following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.mydomainname.in
```

More information about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control